# Cannot fetch image OCR computer vision API Cognitive server nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-cognitive-services, botframework

I'm using computer vision Api and  trying to post an image from url to ocr microsoft cognitive services using node js but i get

```
{"code":"InvalidImageUrl","requestId":"a4c68f18-37c1-484d-a044-2f89df963915","message":"Can't fetch the image."}
```

this is my get and post code

```
http.get(url.parse(imageUrl), function (res) {
    res.on('data',function (body) {
        console.log('data from get '+body);
      })    
    res.on('end', function () {


        request.post({
            headers: {                    
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': proccess.env.SUBSKEY
            },
            url: 'http://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation=true',
            encoding: 'binary',
            formdata:{
                file:res
            }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
            console.log('data from post '+body);
        });
    });
});
```

also i'm using the botbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Hi if someone have this same error i solve this using request pipe instead of http get and moving post options to a var

```
request.get(imageUrl).pipe(request.post(postOptions,function(error,response,body) {  

           /*Do some cool stuff
            */
}
));
```